# Queryset v/s List Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, django-queryset

I want to know what is the difference in terms of execution in Django queryset and Django list.

For eg,
List of Objects v/s Queryset of Objects

Will there be much difference in the execution part?

Any Info will help as It can give a clear picture what to use and what not to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

List of Objects is evaluated,
Queryset isn't unless you perform any computation on the data.

List of Objects will consume RAM space, Queryset won't that much.

You can refer Queryset further in the code without actually dealing with data in your memory, list of objects won't allow you to manipulate data that easily.

This is what I think, others can add to it.

Comment: Enlightening,though I didn't get anything about the execution time.

Comment: If the data is only called by Reference and doesn't occupy your RAM space, it will evaluate faster in a queryset.

Answer (score 1):

**QuerySet**:

- can store multiple objects from your database.
- is a special and original type in **Django** but not in **Python**.

**List**:

- can store multiple values.
- is one of 4 built-in types in **Python**.